# Google Script - Form - live update for a text field

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-contacts-api

My client has a huge list of contacts.
I created a form with a scrolling list, in order to select a contact. The issue is that the scrolling list is too long.
Is there a way (and if so, how?) for my client to start typing the first letters of a contact name, so the 'field area' (or other) fills in automatically the correspondant contact name?
Thank you in advance for your help.
Kind regards,

Comment: What suggests Momin requires that you drop the google form and write an app script application that serves a web page: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

Comment: So if i understand. I create a form with https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/ and it's in this form i can make some ajax-like ? (i am a php dev not javascript and i start with the google app script)

Comment: exactly. You have to write both the client (as HTML+JS page) and the server (that replies to certain AJAX request in order to query App Script accordingly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the select with this javascript:

```
function updateSelect(vA)
{
  var select = document.getElementById("sel1");//or whatever you select id is
  select.options.length = 0; 
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
  }
}
```

The html select element:

```
<select id="sel1">
      <option value="" selected></option>
   </select>
```

I often load selects when the page loads with something like this:

```
$(function(){
google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateSelect)
          .getSelectOptions();//a gs function which passes an array to updateSelect via the success handler
 });
```

That way I can use a spreadsheet to store the values that I want.  In your case you may want to filter them alphabetically perhaps.  And you might want to pass the getSelectOptioptions() function or whatever you call it a parameter to determine how to filter the list.